# How to make a picture cover the whole screen

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to make a picture cover the whole screen. What do I miss and what have I typed wrong? Do i need everything?

HTML

```
<img src="Universet.jpg" id="universet">
```

CSS

```
#universet { 

    height: 100%; 

    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

}
```

Comment: ?? there is no background-image and what are the 100% of height calculated from ? both answer/fix will give the clue why it is not working ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to make this image the background image of your whole page you can set it on the body element like so:

```
body {
   background-image: url("Universet.jpg");
}
```

you may need additional styling to get it just to your liking depending on image size.

Comment: Then the picture repeats itself down the page. I just want it to show one time, so that when i scroll down the backgroundcolor shows:)

Comment: use some of the parts of your original code like background-repeat: no-repeat; and your background color which should solve this for you. again you may need to fix your position wether you want it to be in the center or not, but your original code should help that.

Comment: woo! I'm glad :D